# Passing context between Actors

Tags: akka, actor

I have an Actor A which builds up and returns Employee information for each request it gets. Actor A needs to fetch some more info from another actor B. B in turn fetches some info from Actor C and C is dependent on Actor D.

One way of accomplishing this is to pass the execution context between Actors as Request/Response messages. Is there a better way to manage the context? I could think of two alternatives -

1) Pass the Employee information only to the downstream actors and have Actor D send it back to A. We keep building the Employee information in each actor, much like the Accumulator pattern. So the messages flow: A -> B -> C -> D -> A

2) Create one instance of all Actors per request. This way, the Employee information at each step can be stored locally with each Actor instance.

For a real-world problem, which approach should be preferred?

Comment: Imagine you have to solve this problem with people.  How would you do it then?  (Thought exercise stolen from Viktor Klang)